# How to impose constraints on drop lists of two fields of the same layer?

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes, pyqgis-3

Is it possible to impose with pyqgis3.0 some constraints on a drop list of a field attribute in order to govern the drop list attributes of another linked field?
To better clarify this issue, I attach the following schema:
When I select the Attribute 1.1 of the field 1, then the drop list of the field 2 should be limited to: Attribute 1.2, Attribute 2.2, Attribute 3.2.
Ect.
[image]